# Convert array variable to csv

Tags: php, csv

I have a variable, which holds my array from the database which are names and e-mail addresses.

Array structure is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [fname] => FName [lname] => LName [email] => Email )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [fname] => FName [lname] => LName [email] => Email )
)
```

And so on through the list of all users

I already have all the set up in the framework to create the csv file, I am just having trouble building the foreach loop to iterate through the array variable and put that information into the csv. I've tried a few different ways and I just get errors loaded into the csv. I already have headers in place.

```
    $users = SiteUser::select()->getColumns('fname, lname, email');

    foreach ($users as $u) {
        // print each user as a CSV row (columns are name, email)
        // Anything here will be place into the csv file for download
    }


    exit;
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: I tried that, it isn't what I need

Comment: How are you saving the csv in your framework and what are the errors you are getting when you try? Mayhaps you need to convert your `stdClass` to an array first?

Comment: It's already an array in a  variable. The variable holds the entire array, so I don't really know what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the `stdClass` to an array, and then output with `fputcsv`:

```
// Get pointer to standard output
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// write column headers
fputcsv($fp, ["name", "email"]);

foreach ($users as $u) {
    // assemble array and write
    fputcsv($fp, [$u->fname . " " . $u->lname, $u->email]);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I didn't realize I needed to open the file and close it, I thought the function in the framework's model that had been set up already did that, but apparently not. I also have never worked with an stdclass before.